# Flutter device orientation change not working like native android

Tags: flutter, dart, orientation, landscape-portrait

When I try to move from the current screen to the next screen which has the Landscape orientation by declaring:
***SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);***
However, the application rotates the current screen in landscape mode before going to the next screen. When came back the designs were getting messed up.

[image]

Thanks in advance.